# JPA + Hibernate in a JBoss Cluster

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, cluster-computing

Assume that I have a Scheduled Bean that executes some pooling over a table and deploy it over a JBoss Clustered Domain environment.

1 - Does this Scheduled bean will be deployed in all instances of the Cluster?

---

2 - If the answer to 1 is yes, then when the scheduled bean of Cluster Node #1 runs it and a set or rows from my table is selected is is it possible that a few moments later, while the Cluster Node #1 is still running the Scheduled Bean and Cluster Node #2 runs it´s Scheduled Bean, this bean selects the same set of rows or a partition of this set used by Cluster Node #1 Scheduled Bean?

---

3 - if so, what would happen?  The Scheduled Bean #2 would be waiting until Scheduled Bean #1 finishes and then perform the select?  Scheduled Bean #2 would be allowed to select and I would have a repetition of what was done by Scheduled Bean #1?  Scheduled bean #2 would recieve an Exception when trying to execute?

Thanks a lot, guys

Comment: What version of JBossAS?

Comment: Jboss Wildfly 8.1 RC2